# Can you programmatically add external users to Google Groups?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-cloud-identity

I am building a mailing list for customers using Google Groups. I am trying to programmatically sync customer email addresses from a contact database to a preexisting Google Group using the Cloud Identity API ([link](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest)). It works for email addresses in our organization, but I am getting a 403 for non-Google addresses when invoking the `create` method for the `groups.membership` resource ([link](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/groups.memberships/create)). The specific error is `Error(2028): Permission denied for resource groups/******** (or it may not exist).`

I am hoping that non-Google email addresses can be added to groups with the API. Below are variations of what I have tried so far.

#### Configuration Details

- Create a project in GCP specifically for this automation.
- Create a service account in the project.
- Enable domain wide delegation for the service account with the following scopes:

  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-identity.groups
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-identity
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-identity.groups.readonly
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
- Enable "Group owners can allow external members" in Groups for Business section of Admin console.
- Set "Who can join group" in group settings to "Invited users only" and "Anyone on the web can ask".
- Enable "Allow external members" in group settings.

#### Request Details

- Authenticate as service account (who is a group owner).
- Impersonate user from service account (user is group owner and creator).
- Set `preferred_member_key.EntityKey.id` to customer's email address.
- Set `roles[].MembershipRole.name` to `MEMBER`.

I have also confirmed that the email address can be added through the Groups UI. My suspicion is that it has to do with the `EntitityKey` ([link](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/EntityKey)), but I haven't found a value that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find out whether this is possible with the Cloud Identity API. But it is possible to add external users to a Google Group using the Admin SDK, specifically the `members.insert` method for the Directory API ([link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members/insert)). Just make sure that the `Member` in your request has `type` set to `EXTERNAL`.